# In a binomial experiment, which will produce a probability distribution with the smallest standard deviation, given n is the same for each situation?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A. P = 0.5

B. P = 0.4

C. P = 0.3

D. P = 0.9

E. (1-P) =0.8

No idea where to even start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binomial distributions have two parameters, and are given by  $Binomial(np, np(1-p))$ where the first is the mean and the second is the variance. A has a variance of n(.5)(.5)=.25n, the largest, while D has a variance of n(.9)(.1)=.09n. Thus since n is fixed, D is the answer. Intuitively, a binomial distribution is the number of successes in n trials with probability p of success. What you found is there is less variability in the number of successes when p is large (or small) as opposed to being about even chance of success and failure.

Answer (score 0):

The variance for a binomial distribution is: $np(1-p)$. Therefore the standard deviation will be $SD = \sqrt{np(1-p)}$. The question asks you to minimize $SD$, given that $n$ is fixed, i.e. the only variable is $p$.
Let $$f(p) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{np-np^2}$$
Now in order to minimize the function $f$, you can take the first-order derivative and equate it to $0$, thereby getting a condition on $p$.